# How can I play an AAC file which I obtain from a parse server?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, parse-platform, avaudioplayer

Here is a code snippet from my program. I get the data from the PFFile, get the NSURL, and then finally the NSDATA which I pass to my audio player. Nothing plays though and I don't know why.

```
var audioFile: PFFile = sound!["file"] as! PFFile
audioFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock { (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (error == nil) {
        let audioURLString = audioFile.url!
        let audioURL = NSURL(string: audioURLString)!
        println(audioURL)      //<-- this prints http://files.parsetfss.com/1d4f1088-a07c-43c7-ada2-7f246e6a8167/tfss-db262c85-f6ba-4a5e-a065-9f9e345a929a-sound.aac

        let audioData = NSData(contentsOfURL: audioURL)!
        println(audioData)     // <--this prints 0000001c 66747970 4d344120 00000000....
        let player = AVAudioPlayer(data: audioData, error: nil)
        println(player)        // <-- this prints <AVAudioPlayer: 0x174200200>
        player.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: just looking at your code, you're obtaining a valid url from parse (audioURL), So, rather than use AVAudioPlayer (i believe this requires a local url if memory serves me well), simply create a new instance of AVPlayer, passing in audioURL or create an AVPlayerItem from the audioURL and pass that to the new AVPlayer. Of course, if you want the "Player" to be around after the method ends, you should create a property.

Comment: okay so i added `var playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: audioURL) var player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem) player.play()'` but it still behaves the same way, @MDB983

Comment: i believe your problem is related to the fact you create your item/player on a background thread. create the Player outside of your callback and add the playeritem on the main queue.

Comment: That was it! i used dispatch_asynch to play it on the main thread:) thank you